# Alamofire changes multipart/form-data encoding depending on input

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Working on an iOS project I found out that Alamofire changes the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` of a `multipart/form-data` field depending on the field value.

## Goal

Update an image with some informations (unicode strings) to an endpoint.

## Details

I define the form's fields values as follows:

```
let formFields: [String: String] = [
    "key": _model
]
```

I upload the entire form (image + informations) as follows:

```
Alamofire.upload(
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        // 1. The form's fields
        for (key, value) in formFields {
            guard let byteString = value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) else { continue }
            multipartFormData.append(byteString, withName: key)
        }

        // 2. The picture
        let fileName = "file.jpeg"
        multipartFormData.append(pictureData, withName: ParameterKeys.BikeImage, fileName: fileName, mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    },

    to: _url,
    method: .post,

    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {

        case .success(let upload, _, _):        /* Called when the encoding succeds. */
            upload.validate(statusCode: 200..<300)

            upload.uploadProgress { progress in // main queue by default
                progressHandler(progress)
            }

            upload.response { (response) in
                responseHandler(response)
            }

        case .failure(let error):       /* Called when the encoding fails. */
            failureHandler(error)
        }
    }
)
```

## Behaviour 0

- `_model` is `"Standard"` ✅
- `multipartFormData.append(byteString, ...)` appends `"5374616e64617264"` in the form ✅
- The server gets `"Standard"` without `Content-Transfer-Encoding` ⁉️

## Behaviour 1

- `_model` is `"Ström Bike"` ✅
- `multipartFormData.append(byteString, ...)` appends `"537472c3b66d2042696b65"` in the form ✅
- The server gets `"Str=C3=B6m Bike"` with `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable` ⁉️

## Behaviour 2

- `_model` is `"Abräcadabra"` ✅
- `multipartFormData.append(byteString, ...)` appends `"416272c3a463616461627261"` in the form ✅
- The server gets `"QWJyw6RjYWRhYnJh"` with `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` ⁉️

## Conclusion

On the server, I cannot determine the format of the form data. Is there a way to specify the type of encoding to use for the form fields?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Alamofire doesn't add `Content-Transfer-Encoding` itself, just `Content-Disposition` and `Content-Type` in the multipart body. Where are you seeing this header?

Comment: Hi, I see those headers on the server. Specifically a python webApp running on Google App Engine. I was able to dump the entire incoming client request and in the 3 different cases it shows up with 3 different `Content-Transfer-Encoding`.

Comment: I'd guess that `URLSession` adds that header automatically, and it's up to the server to respond appropriately.

Comment: I will further investigate.